# Return Lync presence with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, lync, user-presence

I am working on a solution to a problem at work where we can't tell if someone is on the phone or just sitting there.  We use Microsoft Lync to place our calls and I was hoping to be able to add a bit of code to an existing .net application to show the presence of the person logged into the machine.  That info will send that out via USB to an indicator light I previously built.

So basically I am trying to create a .net version of those 'ON AIR' lights you see at radio stations.

I have been searching for the last few days and haven't found a solution.  I also downloaded the Microsoft Lync Controls SDK, but no luck with that either.

Answer (score 1):

The following site provides a couple of ways of getting the user availability:  http://rcosic.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/availability-presence-in-lync-client/

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in the BusyLight if you still haven't implemented this solution. It's a USB light which shows your presence, as you describe.

There's a video demo of it in action [here](http://lyncdup.com/2012/04/video-demo-of-busylight-uc-for-microsoft-lync/).